# vowpal wabbit: --multiclass_oaa does not produce probabilities

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I've tried

```
vw --multilabel_oaa 68 -d vw_data.csv --loss_function=logistic --probabilities -p probabilities.txt
```

and ended up with target labels only in probabilities.txt. Also `-r` option designed to produce raw output returned nothing, unfortunately.

Apart from that, I'm not sure is there a way to achieve similar behaviour (multilabel prediction with logistic loss) with other available VW multiclass options such as `--csoaa` and `--wap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember exactly, but I think `--probabilities` does not support multilabel. I even don't know what would be the interpretation (modelling the probability of label co-occurrence? and providing the probabilities for all 2^68 subsets?).

You can use standard multi-class `--oaa 68`. With `--probabilities` it should [predict the probability for each class](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Predicting-probabilities), so you can use e.g. some kind of threshold for selecting multiple lables=classes for each example (e.g. such that the sum of their probabilities is at least 42%).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I can't figure out is there any way to use `--oaa` option with multiple labels per example -- the feature I needed, so I ended up using  `--multilabel_oaa` in the first place.

Comment: Oh, I see - your training data have multiple labels per example. This is not possible with `--oaa`. But you can use [`--csoaa`](http://users.umiacs.umd.edu/~hal/tmp/multiclassVW.html) - if an example has e.g. labels 2, 3 and 5, you should encode it as `1:1 2:0 3:0 4:1 5:0 6:1 7:1 ... 68:1 | features`, where "..." stands for all the labels 8...67, which you need to specify with cost 1 as well.

Comment: I very much appreciate your help. Though I had further problems with making `--csoaa` use logistic loss, as I needed (it seems that it does not work with other losses), I was able to fix some code in vw to gather raw predictions from `--multilabel_oaa`. I'm looking forward to making a pull request to hopefully fix the issue.